# Objective c How to prevent SLComposeViewController to not to share post via Facebook app in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

I am using SLComposeViewController to share a post on facebook including image and Url.

Earlier it works fine when we provide account details in the iPhone settings/facebook.

But now it is sharing post using the app installed on my iPhone.

I want to share post only using social composer like as following

[image: Required feature]

But recently even we dont provide fb account details on settings it is sharing through the facebook app, which we dont want.

***`But dont want to share via facebook app as follows`***

[image: Not like this]

Answer (score 0):

Latest update on FB is not supporting pre-populated text. Its only support #tag text & image or url.

Please read this FB doc:- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios